# Angularjs directive: Isolated scope and attrs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see the example [here](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/master/app/js/directives/fmRating.js)

```
foodMeApp.directive('fmRating', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      symbol: '@',
      max: '@',
      readonly: '@'
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      attrs.max = scope.max = parseInt(scope.max || 5, 10);
...
```

Angular needs `symbol` , `max`, `readonly` to be defined in the isolated scope object to access it from parent scope.

it is used [here](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/master/app/views/menu.html)

`<fm-rating ng-model="$parent.restaurant.price" symbol="$" readonly="true"></fm-rating>`

So, what is the purpose of `attrs`? Can't one access all the attributes passed through `attrs`. Why can't one access value of max as `attrs.max` instead of `scope.max`

Why assign back like `attrs.max = scope.max` ?

Since this app is written by Angular authors, I expect a reason.

thanks.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope/14063373#14063373

Answer (score 96, accepted):

> what is the purpose of attrs?

Attributes defined on the same element as your directive have a few purposes:

1. They are the only way to pass information into a directive that uses an isolate scope.  Since the directive isolate scope doesn't prototypically inherit from the parent scope, we need a way to specify what we want to pass to the isolate scope.  '@', '=', and '&' in the "object hash" therefore each require an attribute to specify what data/information is being passed.
2. They serve as an inter-directive communication mechanism.  (E.g., [Managing communication between independent AngularJS directives independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639399/managing-communication-between-independent-angularjs-directives-independenly/14298481#14298481))
3. They [normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289459/html-element-attribute-names-with-hyphens-are-auto-converted-to-camelcase/14289581#14289581) the attribute names.

> Can't one access all the attributes passed through attrs?

Yes you can, but

1. you will not have any data binding.

   '@' sets up one-way "string" databinding (parent scope → directive isolate scope)  With @ the value you see/get in the directive is always a string, so don't use this if you're trying to pass an object to your directive.

   '=' sets up two-way databinding (parent scope ↔ directive isolate scope).

   Without databinding, your directive can't $watch or $observe model/data changes automatically.
2. attribute values with `{{}}`s will cause you problems, since they will not be interpolated.

   Suppose we have `<my-directive name="My name is {{name}}">` and the parent scope has `$scope.name='Mark'`.  Then, inside the linking function, `console.log(attrs.name)` results in `undefined`. 

   If name is an isolate scope property defined with '@', then `attrs.$observe('name', function(val) { console.log(val) })` results in `My name is Mark`.  (Note that inside the linking function, $observe() must be used to get the interpolated value.)

> Why can't one access value of max as attrs.max instead of scope.max

answered above

> Why assign back like attrs.max = scope.max ?

The only reason I can think of for doing this is in case some other directive needs to see this attribute/value (i.e., inter-directive communication).  However, the other directive would need to run after this directive for this to work (which can be controlled somewhat with the `priority` directive setting).

Summary: in a directive with an isolate scope, normally you don't want to use `attrs`.  (I suppose it could be a way to send initialization data/values into a directive -- i.e., if you don't need databinding for these values and you don't need interpolation.)

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I applaud your effort, and especially enjoyed your article https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance . Great work.

Answer (score 4):

Using attrs you are able to access the attributes defined in your html tag like

```
<fm-rating ng-model="$parent.restaurant.price" symbol="$" readonly="true">
```

So in this case you will have access to the **symbol** and **readonly** attributes. Every attribute you define in your custom directive will be available to the **attrs** variable.

The block:

```
attrs.max = scope.max = parseInt(scope.max || 5, 10);
```

Will **parse and assign** the current **scope.max** value or **5**, if non existent, to the scope.max and attrs.max. This way, **after the assignment you can read from attrs.max**. Before that the attrs.max property in undefined.

Inspecting the fmRating.js source i don't know why/where/when this piece of code is being used.