# Custom directive scope vs attrs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one concern when creating a custom directive in angular.
When I'm using a link function, I'm not sure what is the real difference when accessing attributes with attrs or scope.
Take this piece of code for example:

```
myApp.directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: '=title'
        },
        template: '<img/>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.title) {
                // do something here
            }
            if (attrs.title){
                // do something here
            }
        },
    }
```

From my observations accessing 'title' attribute from attrs and by scope has a similar effect. What is the real difference?

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300986/angularjs-directive-isolated-scope-and-attrs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The difference is that attribute is of a String type by definition. Always. In your case `attrs.title` will be literally string equal to whatever you pass into attribute in HTML.

However, `scope.title` is parsed and evaluated result of the attribute `attr.title`.

Ex. If you use something like this in HTML

```
<some-directive title="name"></some-directive>
```

where `$scope.name = "Thomas Mann"` defined in the scope, then `attr.title` will be string `"name"`, while `scope.title` will be `"Thomas Mann"`.

Comment: Awesome answer. To add to that, you can also do `scope.$eval(attrs.title)` to get a parsed version of the attribute within the context of the scope.

Comment: That's all? I think when you use @ for binding scope it is also being passed as string so it has same effect, right?

Comment: @Marcin86, pretty much something passed into an attribute is a string, and something passed as a scope variable can be whatever data type. But you can also do `scope.$eval(attrs.title)` to evaluate the attribute in the context of the scope, as I commented above.